# How to convert rows into columns and vice versa using browser side scripting of html page?

Tags: jquery, html

## Is there any jquery method revert row into columns and vice versa?

Page tag draws an a4 sized sheet using css.
This table is generated via PHP code but we cannot print column first and add them to same row so I have to do all of this using browser side scripting.

```
<page size="A4" class="flex-container">
  <div class="divTable flex-container" style="width: 70%;border: 2px solid #000;">
    <div class="divTableBody">
      <div class="divTableRow">
        <div class="divTableCell">
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">1
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">101
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">2
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">102
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">3
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">103
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="divTableRow">
        <div class="divTableCell">4
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">104
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">5
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">105
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">6
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">106
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">7
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="divTableRow">
        <div class="divTableCell">107
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">8
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">108
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">9
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">109
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">10
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">110
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="divTableRow">
        <div class="divTableCell">11
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">111
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">12
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">112
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">13
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">113
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">14
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="divTableRow">
        <div class="divTableCell">114
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">15
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">115
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">16
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">116
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">17
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">117
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="divTableRow">
        <div class="divTableCell">18
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">118
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">19
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">119
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">20
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">120
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">21
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</page>
```

## I have found below code on SO but i cannot understand how to apply this on div. I am not a professional developer yet so please help me

```
<script>
$("a").click(function(){
$("table").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var newrows = [];
    $this.find("tr").each(function(){
        var i = 0;
        $(this).find("td").each(function(){
            i++;
            if(newrows[i] === undefined) { newrows[i] = $("<tr></tr>"); }
            newrows[i].append($(this));
        });
    });
    $this.find("tr").remove();
    $.each(newrows, function(){
        $this.append(this);
    });
});
return false;
});
</script>
```

## Here is my css

```
body {
padding-top: 50px;
}
page {
background: white;
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
page[size="A4"] {  
width: 29.7cm;
height: 21cm;
align-content: center; 
}
.divTableCell{
border: 1px solid #999999;
display: table-cell;
width: 200px;
align-content: center;
align-items: center;
text-align: center;
height: 40px;
}
.divTableRow {
display: table-row;
width: inherit;
}
.flex-container{
display: -webkit-box;  /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6, BB7 */
display: -ms-flexbox;  /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
display: -webkit-flex; /* NEW - Safari 6.1+. iOS 7.1+, BB10 */
display: flex;         /* NEW, Spec - Firefox, Chrome, Opera */

justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
background-color: #ffffff;
}
@media print {
body, page {
margin: 0;
box-shadow: 0;
}
}
```

Comment: if you change the table elements do its equivalent divs should give you the result you expect... e.g: `table` = `.divTableBody`, `tr` = `.divTableRow` and `td` = `.divTableCell` (instead of `<tr></tr>` should be `<div class='divTableRow'></div>`

Comment: *`side scripting`* ? what is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no CSS to work on but I just checked the function and it works great.

Use this to build your code.

```js
$("a").click(function(){
$(".divTableBody").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var newrows = [];
    $this.find(".divTableRow").each(function(){
        var i = 0;
        $(this).find(".divTableCell").each(function(){
            i++;
            if(newrows[i] === undefined) { newrows[i] = $("<div class='divTableRow'></div>"); }
            newrows[i].append($(this));
        });
    });
    $this.find(".divTableRow").remove();
    $.each(newrows, function(){
        $this.append(this);
    });
});
return false;
});
```

```css
body {
padding-top: 50px;
}
page {
background: white;
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
page[size="A4"] {  
width: 29.7cm;
height: 21cm;
align-content: center; 
}
.divTableCell{
border: 1px solid #999999;
display: table-cell;
width: 200px;
align-content: center;
align-items: center;
text-align: center;
height: 40px;
}
.divTableRow {
display: table-row;
width: inherit;
}
.flex-container{
display: -webkit-box;  /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6, BB7 */
display: -ms-flexbox;  /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
display: -webkit-flex; /* NEW - Safari 6.1+. iOS 7.1+, BB10 */
display: flex;         /* NEW, Spec - Firefox, Chrome, Opera */

justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
background-color: #ffffff;
}
@media print {
body, page {
margin: 0;
box-shadow: 0;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">test</a>
<page size="A4" class="flex-container">
  <div class="divTable flex-container" style="width: 70%;border: 2px solid #000;">
    <div class="divTableBody">
      <div class="divTableRow">
        <div class="divTableCell">
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">1
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">101
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">2
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">102
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">3
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">103
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="divTableRow">
        <div class="divTableCell">4
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">104
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">5
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">105
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">6
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">106
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">7
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="divTableRow">
        <div class="divTableCell">107
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">8
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">108
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">9
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">109
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">10
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">110
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="divTableRow">
        <div class="divTableCell">11
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">111
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">12
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">112
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">13
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">113
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">14
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="divTableRow">
        <div class="divTableCell">114
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">15
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">115
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">16
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">116
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">17
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">117
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="divTableRow">
        <div class="divTableCell">18
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">118
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">19
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">119
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">20
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">120
        </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">21
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</page>
```

Comment: It crystallize all inputs see before https://ibb.co/m31y2F after
https://ibb.co/bWFQhF  . Could i have to post my css too.

Comment: @AnandBhatnagar please post the CSS will check later

Comment: i have posted my css - @NarenMurali

Comment: @AnandBhatnagar I made the correction, I had done a small mistake